# If God created the earth in Supernatural what about the pagan gods?

Tags: supernatural

If God AKA Chuck created the earth then why in *Hammer of the Gods* do the pagan gods say that "you westerners think the earth is yours" and that "they" were there first? Surely if God, AKA Chuck, created the earth then he and his angels etc. were there first.

Comment: Because *Supernatural* is inconsistent?

Comment: If its anything similar to mutliverses like DC then usually Creator stops doing anything after the creation with devils and angels doing very little. Gods are simple very powerful beings that feed on worship. Saying "We've been here first" simply means "We've been worshipped here first"

Comment: @Yasskier Dunno if you've seen Supernatural, but you're very close.

Comment: @Izkata I've seen few Season 1 episodes. But the approach I've described is seen in quite a few setting that try to match the monotheistic and polytheistic religions.

Comment: Posturing? Odin and Zao Shen argue about the validity of their respective belief systems and which one is older. If they were first, wouldn't arguments regarding giant turtles, serpents and wolves be unnecessary?

Comment: The pagan gods were created later by the power of human belief.  In essence the pagan gods were created by their worshipers.  They would therefore come into existence believing the same mythology that their worshipers had created as if it had actually happened.

Comment: Has it been confirmed that Chuck is indeed the God?

Comment: @DavidCram Do you have a source on that? I know the show has dealt with Tulpas on at least one occasion but, to my knowledge, they never explained the origin of the Pagan deities. I just figured they were another kind of monster.

Comment: I don't have a source, just some hazy recollection about human worship being the source of their power, which would imply that they cannot have pre-dated or created humanity. So I could be wrong.

Comment: According to the Supernatural wiki, the Carrigans (Pagan gods in "A Very Supernatural Christmas") once "had many willing worshipers who gave them sacrifices" but in the world with Christianity "they lost almost all of their followers, and without sacrifices they were weakened." It indicates the sacrifices as the source of their power, however, and not the worship/faith of their followers. Interestingly, they survive for 2,000 years with no followers to speak of but still taking (unwilling) sacrifices. That might be what you're thinking of?

Comment: Where is it stated that God created earth and mankind? Isn't it possible that god was created the same way as the pagans were? Just that he is the most powerful today?

Answer (score 2):

The episode *The Gamblers* finally explained it: God created them to take the blame for the atrocities he caused.

> God created the world, but you know who created us gods? You did. You humans. Sort of. When you apes first climbed down from the trees, you didn't pray to him. You prayed to the -- the sun, the womb, the rain and the stars. Well, at first, the Creator was furious. How dare you not recognize his beneficence? But soon enough, he birthed us -- Ra, Anu, Hera, Mixcoatl, all the rest. (...) To take the blame. Bad harvest? Stillborn child? Our bad. Not his. Plus, we made for epic stories. But, his ego could only handle that for so long. Now he's happy to hide behind whatever religion has the best syndication deal. While we survive on scraps in the wilderness.
> —Fortuna in *The Gamblers*

Most pagan gods had since forgotten their origins and thought that they simply came to being, as Fortuna herself stated in the same episode:

> Most gods, they've forgotten. But I'm old. I hold a grudge.

This is the video:

Answer (score 1):

I think Pagan gods were created by humans, I mean by human beliefs.
And we know all through human existence they have worshiped many different gods.   For example: Before Christianity was spread wide there was a Zeus. Which was created by the massive faith of humans, so Zeus was born and believed that he was one of the first gods.

Comment: Sylar, good concept. However, Hellenic Greece is relatively recent. Earlier cultures, just in that region, such as Egypt and Babylon also had their gods. Any was the sky god in Sumeria, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they're a side effect? Perhaps Chuck created planet Earth and endowed it with a life force or something like that, and this life force with time evolved and developed consciousness, becoming the first "god" who later gave birth to the other pagan gods. All of that even before humans were around, since the angels were around before the first life form was out of the oceans. This is like how Castiel stated and Kali said they (pagan gods) were on planet Earth first; that or they're just Tulpas, which would make more sense since their power is based upon the number of worshippers they still have.

Comment: Is it stated anywhere that God predates mankind? He could be just like the other pagan gods just more powerful today?

Answer (score 1):

The pagan gods all exist as a result of belief and worship from mankind. This is discussed when (I don't remember the episode) an elderly couple of gods attempted to sacrifice Sam and Dean to themselves as dinner. This gets mentioned in a few other episodes as well.

The pagan gods likely think that God (Chuck) is just another being fueled by belief, as God seems to have stopped interacting with us a long time ago, meaning they only know of him as a story. Additionally, those other gods had their own worshippers and heard the stories of God(Chuck) later, meaning they probably think he is some young deity, rather than the creator of all.

Lastly, if they ARE created by belief, they are likely results of the belief that they themselves are the creators. That means they might not even realize that all of the stories about them are made up myths, but instead truly believe that they themselves are the original beings.

Answer (score 0):

So what about the other planets in our galaxy or our known universe for that matter? Do any of those planets harbour life that God, aka Chuck, created. I remember Lucifer wanting to bring his son to some other place in the universe to live giving me the impression that that Chuck created other biospheres with life.

I'm just assuming that Earth was like the one that most of his effort and love went into that he created humans in his image. I don't know but for some reason Earth seems to be the center of attention maybe where God's base of operations were (heaven) but they have introduced other world's like the places Charlie travels to. The alternate worlds with another Michael does that mean there is another god or is it the same chuck that looks after all versions with ours being the real one but the others just being every possible outcome in existence playing out in simulation time situations.

I'm hoping that they went deeper than the already super deep mythology. And back to why I originally sought out this post I was curious to whether god really created everything or did he just happen to be the only thing left in the universe with omnipotent power after some unforeseen event. I feel like according to the old gods, they were there first on Earth meaning the Earth existed and humans existed then God came into play created angels and heaven and tinkered with humanity giving them a soul and since he was more powerful than the old gods he really could do whatever. If they are referred to as the old gods then he must of been a new god, or at least a new player to them. Maybe he just wasn't around or didn't interfere with them. Maybe he did create the old gods before the angels to be more godlike like himself when first trying to create beings.

We know he was experimenting with creation because of the leviathan that went bad. So maybe the old gods were another creation experiment to create being a with God like powers but with free will. Seeing as angels are god like beings that were more drone like with a hive mind and humans have the free will but no god like power. It's like he was trying different mix ups trying to get the recipe right.

Comment: I've edited in some paragraph breaks so this is easier to read but it's still not totally clear. Could you [edit] in a summary to this as to what your answer is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment about how God was more powerful, so he tinkered with humans etc. made the most sense.  In the episode when Lucifer and the pagan gods are together, Lucifer says to Mercury "No wonder you pagans forfeited this planet to us."  But that still doesn't explain Chuck pretty much saying he created the universe with his sister Amara, light and dark..?

So I think Supernatural has some plot holes, which is kind of annoying but it's still my favourite show.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should take the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.  I'm not sure how this answers the question why the pagan gods think that _they_ were first if God _created_ the earth (and must therefore have preceded them).  Perhaps you can edit your answer to specifically address the question?